# Mongod and mongo command not working in termux

Tags: mongodb, termux

I'm getting this error

CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "mongod": library "libicudata.so.69" not found

Comment: make sure to install the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with this stems from the fact that the current version of libicu is 70 as opposed to 69. According to this [comment](https://github.com/its-pointless/its-pointless.github.io/issues/91#issuecomment-974697388) you can try to compile the old version and that should help. Personally I've tried that and it was still unusable due to segfaults, so YMMV